# Q&A app between two phones

Tags: android

I want to write an app where one phone sends a question to another phone and the phone that has the same app installed answers it like yes or no. What is an efficient way to do this? 
I have done some research about c2dm and xmpp but have doubts about that they can cover my requirements. Ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for C2DM in combination with specific Intents to define what the other phone should be doing.

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html

Comment: But I have read that c2dm is only a notification mechanism and not designed for content delivery. So how would I get the answer from the phone that answers the question.

Comment: Upon receiving the notification, you can start an activity with a specific Intent. E.g. like the Intent(Action.VIEW) to view a webpage. You would have to create your own intent, and implement an activity that handles that intent. Good luck

Comment: So you mean create an intent when notification has come pops up on the screen, gets the answer from user and push it to the phone which asks the question. Am I understand you clearly.

Comment: Yes. At least, that's the way I would try to tackle it!